# How to create a new column in R data table where each row is a function of previous row?

Tags: r, recursion, data.table

**How to create a new column in data table where each row is a function of previous row in R?**

For example, i have the below data and function.

```
DT <- data.table(A = c(2,3,4,2,3,4,1,0)) 
FXN = function(x,y) {x+y}
```

Note: I am using x+y is an example function. In reality, the function is a bit more complicated.

I want to create a new column where the new[i] element is a FXN of( new[i-1], A[i])

I can do this using for loop as per below:

```
DT$new <- NA
DT$new[1]<- DT$A[1]
for (i in 2:nrow(DT) )
{
  DT$new[i] = DT$new[i-1]+DT$A[i]
}
```

And I get the desired output:

```
DT
   A new
1: 2   2
2: 3   5
3: 4   9
4: 2  11
5: 3  14
6: 4  18
7: 1  19
8: 0  19
```

Question is: Is there a way to do this without using for-loop? My actual function is a bit more complicated and is taking time.
For example, something like:

```
DT[,new:= FXN(A ,lag(new,1L)) ]
```

But this throws up the error:
Error: Input must be a vector, not a function.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

I ended up hacking a code using Reduce , but that is taking too much time as well.

```
DT$new <- Reduce(FXN, DT$A, acc=TRUE, init=0)[-1]
```

So I am looking for a solution with simple data table or dplyr functions with speed in mind.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is `Reduce` really slow? Try with `DT[, new := Reduce(FXN, A, accumulate = TRUE, init=0)[-1]]`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to `Reduce` `purrr` has `accumulate` function which you can try :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

DT <- DT %>% mutate(new = accumulate(A, FXN, .init = 0)[-1])
```

Comment: Both accumulate (from purrr package) and using Reduce as you suggested show up similar times to what I have with Reduce. Thanks for the try.

Comment: I guess you should then write up a function in Rcpp then.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work:

```
> DT$new <- cumsum(DT$A)
> DT
  A new
1 2   2
2 3   5
3 4   9
4 2  11
5 3  14
6 4  18
7 1  19
8 0  19
```

Checked it with sample data:

```
> start.time <- Sys.time()
> d <- data.frame(val = sample(1:100, 1000000, T))
> d$new <- cumsum(d$val)
> end.time <- Sys.time()
> time.taken <- end.time - start.time
> time.taken
Time difference of 0.1042359 secs
>
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but my function is not exactly cumulative sum. i gave that for illustration purpose only. As mentioned in the question, my actual function is a bit more complicated.